# Flutter - Duplicate class found modules exoplayer

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle, exoplayer

I am getting one error in my flutter project.

```
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.package-info found in modules jetified-exoplayer-common-2.14.1-runtime (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-common:2.14.1) and jetified-exoplayer-ui-2.12.3-runtime (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.12.3)
```

pubspec.yaml

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.7
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
  cached_network_image: ^3.1.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  smooth_page_indicator: ^1.0.0+2
  dotted_line: ^3.1.0
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.0
  event_bus: ^2.0.0
  dio: ^4.0.4
  connectivity_plus: ^2.0.3
  package_info: ^2.0.2
  device_info: ^2.0.3
  hive: ^2.0.4
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  ars_progress_dialog: ^0.0.1
  url_launcher: ^6.0.10
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+4
  image_cropper: ^1.4.1
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.1
  geocoding: ^2.0.1
  flutter_google_places: ^0.3.0
  google_maps_webservice: ^0.0.19
#  geocoder: ^0.2.1
  dotted_border: ^2.0.0
  flutter_html: ^2.2.0
  flutter_zoom_sdk: ^1.0.0+1


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

i try to find some solution but nothing is working. Pls, anyone guide me.

Comment: yeah i have the same issue,, but could fix till now.. Actually this error is due to flutter_zoom_sdk plugin

Answer (score 0):

flutter_html: ^2.2.0 package is incompatible with flutter_zoom_sdk: ^1.0.0+1